# Query cost estimation in databricks sql warehouse

Tags: databricks, databricks-sql

Our sql warehouse in databricks is shared among many teams. Some have few queries to run and some teams have large queries on large tables. How can I attribute cost on this shared resource.
What all we know of a query
DAtabricks provide few metrics around query runs like

- Query runtime
- Query memory usage
- Rows scanned

Also we know the DBUs a sql warehouse is consuming.
We were thinking of using the memory consumed by the query to calculate the cost by getting the cost of running per mb/ per sec

Let me know if there are better ways to doing it